# Why am I getting this error - 'TypeError: Can only call FormData.append on instances of FormData' even though I'm using an instance of FormData only?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my input element in HTML :

```
<input name = 'files' multiple id = 'upload_btn' type="file" value="Upload" accept = '.jpg'>
```

I have this code in my script tag under send_files fn :

```
var form_data = new FormData();

for(var i = 0; i < num_files; ++i)
{
    form_data.append('files[]', document.getElementById('upload_btn').files[i]);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tested your code in my PC and it didn't cause any error. Maybe you changed the value of form_data after you assigned new FormData() to that.

Comment: @Pulse Could you please look into this code https://codeshare.io/LwwyYV? It doesn't have many lines.

Comment: Please don't share code outside of Stack Overflow. It's not fair to people who can access Stack Overflow but can't access these other sites. Your question should be able to stand on its own, with a [mre] here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @HereticMonkey gotcha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I checked the code you sent in codeshare and realized that you are getting that  error because of this line:

```
var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById('upload_btn'));
```

You're not supposed to send any element besides "form" element into FormData but you're sending an input element into it.

You have 2 options now:

- Add a form element into your html
- Don't send any element to FormData when you initialize it

**

### First Approach

In html:

```
<form id="yourForm">
  <input name = 'files' multiple id = 'upload_btn' type="file" value="Upload" accept = '.jpg'>
  <input onclick = "send_files()" id = 'convert_btn' type = "submit" value = 'Convert'>
</form>
```

In javascript:

```
var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById('yourForm'));
```

### Second Approach

In javascript:

```
var form_data = new FormData();
```

> Note: In second approach if you console.log(form_data) it will show an empty object. this is because console.log can't show files in FormData directly. If you want to check that files added to FormData or not you can do it like below

after your for loop :

```
for(var df of data_form){
  console.log(df);
}
```

Comment: I didn't really have the 'var form_data...' line like you told before, I was trying out something by inserting that, and put that code instead on codeshare. Even with the old one there was the still problem. I looked into it and found that the real problem was the scope of 'form_data'. It wasn't getting the needed block scope. That fixed the issue. But anyway both your approaches work either way, thanks.

Comment: And processData : false should've been present in the Ajax call!